# How do I format an overloaded c++ input operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to create a vector object that I will be able to use as a vector. However, I am having trouble with the input. I would like to format the input so i can type `3.4i+5.4j-8.4k` and it would put the value accordingly into the the correct variable in the class.

**The Class:**

```
class Vector3D
{
 public:
   Vector3D(double xA, double yA, double zA);
   Vector3D(Points &terminate, Points &start);
   Vector3D(const Vector3D &vec);
   Vector3D();
   double vector_length();
   float compute_hor_angle();
   float compute_vert_angle();
   float get_hor_angle();
   float get_vert_angle();
   double get_length();

   friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,const Vector3D& vec);
   istream& operator >>(istream& in,  Vector3D& vec);
private:
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
   double length;
   float angle_hor;
   float angle_vert;
};
```

**My Attempt:**

```
  istream& Vector3D::operator >>(istream& in, Vector3D& vec)
  {
      char charecter, x,y,z;
      in >> vec.x >> x;
      in >> charecter;
      if(charecter == '-')
      {
          in >> vec.y >> y;
          vec.y = -1*vec.y;
      }
      else
          in >> vec.y >> y;
      in >> charecter;
      if(charecter == '-')
      {
          in >> vec.z >> z;
          vec.z = -1*vec.z;
      }
      else
          in >> vec.z >> z;

   return in;
 }
```

Comment: You should read input as string and then parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  user902384 stated in the comments, you will need to parse the string to appropriately assign your vector values. Your parsing logic can be as complex as needed per requirements, but here is something I threw together that may help get you started:

```
float ParseValue(const std::string& str);

void ParseVectorString(const std::string& equation, Vector3D& vec)
{
    vec.x = vec.y = vec.z = 0.0f;

    if (equation.empty())
        return;

    const size_t I_POSITION = equation.find('i');
    const size_t J_POSITION = equation.find('j');
    const size_t K_POSITION = equation.find('k');

    // Logic assumes order is i, j, k.
    // You can make it smarter if needed.
    unsigned startPosition = 0;
    if (I_POSITION != std::string::npos)
    {
        unsigned length = I_POSITION - startPosition;
        vec.x = ParseValue(equation.substr(startPosition, length));
        startPosition = I_POSITION + 1;
    }

    if (J_POSITION != std::string::npos)
    {
        unsigned length = J_POSITION - startPosition;
        vec.y = ParseValue(equation.substr(startPosition, length));
        startPosition = J_POSITION + 1;
    }

    if (K_POSITION != std::string::npos)
    {
        unsigned length = K_POSITION - startPosition;
        vec.z = ParseValue(equation.substr(startPosition, length));
        startPosition = K_POSITION + 1;
    }
}

// Parse the value from the vector variable.
float ParseValue(const std::string& str)
{
    unsigned startPosition = 0;
    bool isNegativeValue = false;
    if (str[startPosition] == '-')
    {
        isNegativeValue = true;
        startPosition = 1;
    }

    float value = atof(str.substr(startPosition, str.length()).c_str());

    return isNegativeValue ? value*-1 : value;
}
```